# how to create message when loop completed

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have a code working on basic c++. I just want when this loop become completed and one if statement become true, a message generate automatically. In this regard i have used while statement but while statement is also work i don't want to display the message. Means when if statement (congratulation....) become true, the message (You don't have more...) displays.

```
  for(i=1; i<=attempt; i++){
  cout<< "whatever" ;
    cin >> userNumber;
    if (userNumber < secretNumber){
        cout << "Oooppssss... Your entered number is too low..." <<endl;
    }
    else if (userNumber > secretNumber){
        cout << "Oooppssss... Your entered number is too high..."<<endl;
    }
    else if(userNumber==secretNumber){
        cout << "Congratulation you have won..."<<endl;
        break;
    }

    else{
        cout << "Invalid Input."<<endl;
    }
    }
    while(attempt=i){
        cout<< "You don't have more turn...Computer Won."<<endl<<endl;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: This will break when the player wins on the last attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is you are not using `==` and hence condition always turns true. Also instead of while loop you need if

```
while(attempt=i){
```

Use

```
if((attempt + 1) == i){
```

Comment: no, you haven't understand the question. Message is displaying whatever i want. But in the if statement of "Congratulation..." i don't want to use while statement. What should i do there?

Comment: That's better, but when i found the true statement at the point where attempt==i, so there, the message will also be shown. :(

Comment: i used this..
 if (userNumber==secretNumber){
      cout<<"";
     }
     else if(attempt=i){
      cout<< "You don't have more turn...Computer Won."<<endl<<endl;
      
     }